# Grohe shower valve - cartridge replacement, need help identifying replacement part

Tags: plumbing, valve, cartridge

I have this Grohe shower valve from 2000  and cartridge needs to be replaced.  A few places i called, they said they need to know the part number and the number I am seeing on one picture doesn't seem to be the part number.  Can someone help me identify what cartridge i can purchase to replace the one in the picture?[image: valve]

[[image: cartridge][2]]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Google “grohe 41131275”. Look right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste “grohe 41131275” into your search engine.

I did and came up with dozens of cartridges that look to match the one in your picture. One example is [Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LOQRB74). The exact part numbers may not match, however often the manufacturer will change a part number to reflect the year and month of manufacture.

You will have to do your own comparison shopping. Or take the cartridge to a plumbing supply store and they will match it up.

Comment: This is a good approach. Because part numbers are often changed, it can be worthwhile to read the Q&As that accompany the listings: sometimes the Q&As will specifically state that new part number X is a directly replacement for (as in your case) previous part number 41131275.